# $push in nested field works wonky in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema that's something like this

```
firstfield :{
    secondfield:{
        thirdfield  : [ObjectId]
    }
}
```

and i do something like this

```
models.mymodel.update({_id:ObjectId(logId)}, {$push: {"firstfield.secondfield.thirdfield" : ObjectId(userId)}}, function(err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
})
```

Here's the problem. When i give it an existing logId to search for... after it's done, it deletes the whole row.. and creates another one, somehow managing to increment SOME fields (let's assume i have name field set as : mylog_6 (the current row i want to modify) and the maximum is 105.. it will delete that row and create one and it will set the name as mylog_106.

What gives? :)

Comment: Can you post a complete example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Sure thing @JohnnyHK. https://gist.github.com/4287502

Comment: That's better, but I meant standalone code that could be run to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well@JohnnyHK that would mean putting the whole app up and i cant do that. I have no problem except this update. Update works perfectly with push in a top tier array. But when it comes to pushing into a 2 level down nested array it goes wrong. It simply deletes the whole row creates another with a new _id and thats it

Comment: What's `ObjectId` defined as in your example?  I get errors when I try and replicate what you're doing with it set to `mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK. ObjectId is defined as var ObjectId = app.mongoose.Types.ObjectId;  Problem was with MongoVUE. It kept hanging. Learned my lesson and now im checking everything in console.  Thank you for your time though.